# How to make this table sorting script treat different tables differently?

Tags: javascript, sorting, html-table

I found an in itself good table content sorting script. It can sort the contents of multiple tables and is lightweight. However, it makes the default sorting column, determined by one particular value in the script which has to match the HTML sorting, the same for every table. While I have different tables with different characteristics, and thus with different default sorting columns.

Is it possible to make this script assign different tables different default sorting column numbers? This is the -- two-part -- script (see below for what I tried):

first part, separate file:

```
function TSorter(){
    var table = Object;
    var trs = Array;
    var ths = Array;
    var prevSortCol = '3';
    var curSortCol = Object;
    var sortType = Object;

    function get(){}

    function getCell(index){
        return trs[index].cells[curSortCol]
    }

    /*----------------------INIT------------------------------------*/
    // Initialize the variable
    // @param tableName - the name of the table to be sorted
    /*--------------------------------------------------------------*/
    this.init = function(tableName)
    {
        table = document.getElementById(tableName);
        ths = table.getElementsByTagName("th");
        for(var i = 0; i < ths.length ; i++)
        {
            ths[i].onclick = function()
            {
                sort(this);
            }
        }
        return true;
    };


    /*----------------------SORT------------------------------------*/
    // Sorts a particular column. If it has been sorted then call reverse
    // if not, then use quicksort to get it sorted.
    // Sets the arrow direction in the headers.
    // @param oTH - the table header cell (<th>) object that is clicked
    /*--------------------------------------------------------------*/
    function sort(oTH)
    {
        curSortCol = oTH.cellIndex;
        sortType = oTH.abbr;
        trs = table.tBodies[0].getElementsByTagName("tr");

        //set the get function
        setGet(sortType)

        // it would be nice to remove this to save time,
        // but we need to close any rows that have been expanded
        for(var j=0; j<trs.length; j++)
        {
            if(trs[j].className == 'detail_row')
            {
                closeDetails(j+2);
            }
        }

        // if already sorted just reverse
        if(prevSortCol == curSortCol)
        {
            oTH.className = (oTH.className != 'descend' ? 'descend' : 'ascend' ); // reversed from original
            reverseTable();
        }
        // not sorted - call quicksort
        else
        {
            oTH.className = 'descend'; // reversed from original
            if(ths[prevSortCol].className != 'exc_cell'){ths[prevSortCol].className = '';}
            quicksort(0, trs.length);
        }
        prevSortCol = curSortCol;
    }

    /*--------------------------------------------------------------*/
    // Sets the GET function so that it doesnt need to be
    // decided on each call to get() a value.
    // @param: colNum - the column number to be sorted
    /*--------------------------------------------------------------*/
    function setGet(sortType)
    {
        switch(sortType)
        {
            case "link_column":
                get = function(index){
                    return  getCell(index).firstChild.firstChild.nodeValue;
                };
                break;
            default:
                get = function(index){  return getCell(index).firstChild.nodeValue;};
                break;
        };
    }

    /*-----------------------EXCHANGE-------------------------------*/
    //  A complicated way of exchanging two rows in a table.
    //  Exchanges rows at index i and j
    /*--------------------------------------------------------------*/
    function exchange(i, j)
    {
        if(i == j+1) {
            table.tBodies[0].insertBefore(trs[i], trs[j]);
        } else if(j == i+1) {
            table.tBodies[0].insertBefore(trs[j], trs[i]);
        } else {
            var tmpNode = table.tBodies[0].replaceChild(trs[i], trs[j]);
            if(typeof(trs[i]) == "undefined") {
                table.appendChild(tmpNode);
            } else {
                table.tBodies[0].insertBefore(tmpNode, trs[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    /*----------------------REVERSE TABLE----------------------------*/
    //  Reverses a table ordering
    /*--------------------------------------------------------------*/
    function reverseTable()
    {
        for(var i = 1; i<trs.length; i++)
        {
            table.tBodies[0].insertBefore(trs[i], trs[0]);
        }
    }

    /*----------------------QUICKSORT-------------------------------*/
    // This quicksort implementation is a modified version of this tutorial:
    // http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/quicksort/
    // @param: lo - the low index of the array to sort
    // @param: hi - the high index of the array to sort
    /*--------------------------------------------------------------*/
    function quicksort(lo, hi)
    {
        if(hi <= lo+1) return;

        if((hi - lo) == 2) {
            if(get(hi-1) > get(lo)) exchange(hi-1, lo);
            return;
        }

        var i = lo + 1;
        var j = hi - 1;

        if(get(lo) > get(i)) exchange(i, lo);
        if(get(j) > get(lo)) exchange(lo, j);
        if(get(lo) > get(i)) exchange(i, lo);

        var pivot = get(lo);

        while(true) {
            j--;
            while(pivot > get(j)) j--;
            i++;
            while(get(i) > pivot) i++;
            if(j <= i) break;
            exchange(i, j);
        }
        exchange(lo, j);

        if((j-lo) < (hi-j)) {
            quicksort(lo, j);
            quicksort(j+1, hi);
        } else {
            quicksort(j+1, hi);
            quicksort(lo, j);
        }
    }
}
```

second part, in the table page:

```
function init() {
var Table1Sorter = new TSorter;
var Table2Sorter = new TSorter;

Table1Sorter.init('score-x-year-for-one-patho');
Table2Sorter.init('score-x-patho-in-one-year');
```

I tried putting this in several places, but that doesn't work:

```
if (table.id == 'score-x-year-for-one-patho')
    var prevSortCol = '0';
if (table.id == 'score-x-patho-in-one-year')
    var prevSortCol = '3';
```

Anyone know how the script should be altered?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this table sorter is from Terill Dent. See link [HTML Table Sorting JavaScript](http://www.terrill.ca/sorting/) and you can sort table on each column.

How to initialize sorting on each column is described here: [Object Oriented .JS QuickSort - Documentation](http://www.terrill.ca/sorting/documentation.html): "*Before we can get start working with the actual table, we need to initialize the variables inside our TSorter object and add the onclick behaviours to the cells in the table's header row. Caution must be taken when referencing this from inside the onclick handler where this is referring to the cell that is clicked, not TSorter.*"

As I understand you have to define `onclick` event handler for each column in `TSorter()` function.

**EDIT - Wrong:** It seems that default sort column is set to 3 at the beginning of function:

```
var prevSortCol = '3';
```

How to sort on default column? I'd just trigger `click` event in `init()` function for specific column. You can set an ID for column in header, get that ID in `init()` function and trigger `click` event on it. For example:

In table section:

```
    <th id='defaultCol'>Col. name</th>
```

Init section:

```
function init() {
    var TableSorter1 = new TSorter;

    TableSorter1.init('housing_table_1');

    var elem = document.getElementById("defaultCol");
    if (typeof elem.onclick == "function") {
        elem.onclick.apply(elem);
    }
}

window.onload = init;
```

This will work if index of your default sort column is not same as `prevSortCol`. If they are the same you have to change `prevSortCol` and it cannot be set to `-1` or number greater of `number of columns - 1`.

Comment: prevSortCol is indeed set to 3 at the beginning of the function. That is why I tried to change it along with the table's id, with my little `if` block. But that doesn't work -- makes no difference whatsoever. How should I do that? Can it be done in a rather easy manner?